# How do I get the interdiff between these two git commits?

Tags: git

I'm trying to view the difference between two revisions of the same commit in git. A diff of the diffs, basically. From what I've read so far, this is known as the "interdiff". I've read several tutorials on how to create interdiffs of git patches, but I haven't been able to get these methods to work in my particular case.

So here's the setup. I have two diverging branches, each with slightly different commits:

```
* 29e734f - (origin/feature_branch, new_commits) New commit 3 (69 minutes ago) <Ajedi32>
* b22ebea - New commit 2 (89 minutes ago) <Ajedi32>
* 09d42c2 - New commit 1 (2 hours ago) <Ajedi32>
| * 467e08f - (old_commits) Old commit 3 (4 weeks ago) <Ajedi32>
| * f2bf1cb - Old commit 2 (4 weeks ago) <Ajedi32>
| * 34a2187 - Old commit 1 (4 weeks ago) <Ajedi32>
|/  
*   1b05a4a - (origin/base, base) Base commit (5 weeks ago) <Ajedi32>
```

In this example, I want to find the interdiff between "Old commit 3" and "New commit 3". I've tried creating a patch file from these two commits and running them through the `interdiff` utility, but all I got was this:

```
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file /tmp/interdiff-1.Kgwx8u.rej
interdiff: Error applying patch1 to reconstructed file
```

I'm not really sure what that means, so I'm kind of stuck now. Where do I go from here?

Note: I'm am **not** looking for `git diff old_commits new_commits` here. I don't want the revisions to commits 1 and 2 included in the output.

Comment: Oh, and depending on what the OP was trying to ask this might be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1191282/1157054).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the diff of the diffs serve you?

Comment: @Shahbaz You mean what is it useful for? I'm using it to make it easier for the people reviewing my code to see what I changed in response to a previous review. [This page](https://drupal.org/documentation/git/interdiff) is one of the tutorials I followed. It has a pretty good explanation near the top of the page of why interdiffs are useful.

Comment: @Shahbaz Or were you asking what would happen if I ran the content of the diffs through the `diff` command? In that case, I'm not sure but I doubt it would be pretty.

Comment: how is this different from `diff "old_commit_3".."new_commit_3"`?

Comment: @mnagel From the original question: "Note: I'm am not looking for `git diff old_commits new_commits` here. I don't want the revisions to commits 1 and 2 included in the output."

So if there were some minor differences between "Old commit 1" and "New commit 1", I wouldn't want those changes to be included. I'm diffing the patches, not the state of the repo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Git 2.19 introduces a new command, [`git range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff) which does this:

> git-range-diff - Compare two commit ranges (e.g. two versions of a branch)
>
> ```
> git range-diff [--color=[<when>]] [--no-color] [<diff-options>] [--no-dual-color]
>                [--creation-factor=<factor>]\
>                ( <range1> <range2> | <rev1>...<rev2> | <base> <rev1> <rev2> )
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> This command shows the differences between two versions of a patch
> series, or more generally, two commit ranges (ignoring merge commits).
>
> To that end, it first finds pairs of commits from both commit ranges
> that correspond with each other. Two commits are said to correspond
> when the diff between their patches (i.e. the author information, the
> commit message and the commit diff) is reasonably small compared to
> the patches' size. See `Algorithm` below for details.
>
> Finally, the list of matching commits is shown in the order of the
> second commit range, with unmatched commits being inserted just after
> all of their ancestors have been shown.

So, in your case:

```
git range-diff base old_commits new_commits
```

Would automatically match up the commits made in the `old_commits` branch with the commits in the `new_commits` branch, and display a summary of the differences between each commit.

Or, if you just want the changes from the last commit in each of those branches, you'd run:

```
git range-diff old_commits~..old_commits new_commits~..new_commits
```

Since Git 2.31 you can use a more concise form for single commits:

```
git range-diff old_commits^! new_commits^!
```

For more on range-diff, see [the official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like this:

```
git log -p -1 new_commits > patch.new
git log -p -1 old_commits > patch.old
diff patch.old patch.new
```

Or for a terse one-liner (in `bash`):

```
diff <(git log -p -1 old_commits) <(git log -p -1 new_commits)
```

Comment: The bash syntax used for the one-liner is a [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: Is threre a reson to use `git log` instead of `git show`, i.e. something like `diff <(git show old_commits) <(git show new_commits)`?

Comment: @doak Good point - it seems that the output is identical, at least on the version of `git` I'm currently using... That may or may not always be the case, though...

Comment: @talberg, I am pretty sure that this true since at least 10 years and at least for the next two decades as well ;)
From `man git show`: "For commits it shows the log message and textual diff."

Comment: that one-liner seems posix-compliant actually

Answer (score 1):

If there are few differences between the two commits, comparing lines removed and lines added (i.e. only those starting with + or -) is effective. It gets rid of the noise introduced by the hunks boundaries starting with @@ or the commit message body that are not significant:

```
diff -u --ignore-matching-lines '^[^+-]' \
    <(git show 1d9e4ac) <(git show 7b8e5c9)
```

a sample outout is:

```
--- /dev/fd/63  2015-02-13 13:27:08.612683558 +0100
+++ /dev/fd/62  2015-02-13 13:27:08.616683527 +0100
@@ -62,13 +57,24 @@
  }

 diff --git a/src/crush/CrushWrapper.h b/src/crush/CrushWrapper.h
-index 0113662..282cbeb 100644
+index 3b2e6e6..0a633a5 100644
 --- a/src/crush/CrushWrapper.h
 +++ b/src/crush/CrushWrapper.h
-@@ -874,6 +874,25 @@ public:
-     return false;
+@@ -863,6 +863,36 @@ public:
+     if (!crush) return -1;
+     return crush_find_rule(crush, ruleset, type, size);
    }
- 
++
++  bool ruleset_exists(int const ruleset) const {
++    for (size_t i = 0; i < crush->max_rules; ++i) {
++     if (crush->rules[i]->mask.ruleset == ruleset) {
++       return true;
++     }
++    }
++
++    return false;
++  }
++
 +  /**
 +   * Return the lowest numbered ruleset of type `type`
 +   *
```

Answer (score 1):

The GNU interdiff on your 2 patches fails because they have no direct common base / parent.

While a `git range-diff` produces an outer diff of diffs (which is often hard to read; unaware / inconsistent regarding already consumed / merged changes in previous commits; not an applicable patch format), you can get an effective well readable interdiff by merge-rebasing a copy of the one commit onto the parent of the other (preferably newer) commit. There are several ways.

Trivial would be to compare `<New commit 1>` with `<Old commit 1>` in your example because they already have an **immediate common parent**:

```
diff NC1 OC1
```

Further away from the common base, according to your actual question, we get it for example like this:

```
# move to the parent of NC3 - entering detached HEAD state
git checkout NC3~1
# merge-rebase the single patch <Old-commit-3> onto here
git cherry-pick OC3
# show the diff or reverse diff (or diff in gitk GUI)
git diff -R NC3
# back to feature_branch
git checkout feature_branch
```

Of course merge conflicts may appear here - which then (necessarily) expose changes that are not compatible to a sort of interdiff with 'virtual common base' due to the lack of a real direct common parent.

A (temporary) tag or branch could be created to conserve this rebased *comparison commit* (or range of commits) - e.g. for discussion and work with other users. Otherwise the temporary unreferenced dangling commit(s) would be auto-recycled soon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would give you something like what you want. But it will fail if commits 1-2-3 are very dependent.

```
$ git checkout 'old commit 2'
$ git cherry-pick -n 'new commit 3'
$ git diff 'old commit 3'

$ git checkout 'new commit 2'
$ git cherry-pick -n 'old commit 3'
$ git diff 'new commit 3'
```