# What are two and three way diff/merge?

Tags: git

```
1 <- 2 <- 5 (merge commit) <- master <- HEAD
 \       /
  3 <-- 4 <- dev
```

1. Is two way merge uses only commits `2` and `4` during the a merge? If I am right, then in which situations a two way merge is used?
2. What is a two way diff?
3. What is a three way diff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think anyone really talks about "two way diffs"; they are just "diffs".  In practice I don't see the phrase "three way diffs" used either, but in version control, it is the obvious label for a pair of diffs starting from a common merge base, looking at two subsequent but divergent snapshots.  (You might also look up "interdiff".  See [How do I get the interdiff between these two git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17792768/1256452) and https://linux.die.net/man/1/interdiff.)

The term *merge* has multiple meanings, and is (for instance, unrelated to Git) well-defined when talking about [K-way merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms).  However, when it comes to version control (more general than just Git), the phrase *three way merge* is quite specific, and refers to a merge that starts with a *merge base* version, from which there are two divergences.

Using the fact that version control systems have defined "three way merge", some people have made a kind of [back-formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation) to call the process of applying a single diff a "two-way merge".  This is not a good term, in my opinion, as there is no real merging going on.  Just call it "applying a diff" or "applying a patch".

See also [Why is a 3-way merge advantageous over a 2-way merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/1256452)  Note that the comment that talks about a 4 or even 5 way merge is not really applicable to Git.

You *can* use `git diff --full-index <commit1> <commit2> | git apply -3` to make Git do three-way merges on individual files, where each merge base version of each file is selected individually from the `index` line.  However, this is essentially the same as choosing all the files associated with `<commit1>` as the merge base.  The way this works is that `git diff` prints the hash ID of each blob in its output, and if `git apply` is unable to apply the patch as-is, Git will use the printed blob ID to locate the original file, then compute a second diff from that merge base version to the current version of the file.<sup>1</sup>  It then feeds the two diffs into the merge machinery.  (See also [the `git merge-file` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-file.html).)  But note that the blob hash of each file *in* `<commit1>` is determined strictly by the *tree* object attached to `<commit1>`.  This is therefore no different from saying *the files associated with `<commit1>`*.  That is, it's no different with one exception: if Git has the commit hash ID, or the corresponding tree ID, Git can do a tree-wide file comparison to look for rename operations, after which Git can associate the merge base's file path *P<sub>B</sub>* with a *different* path *P<sub>L</sub>*, the "local" or `--ours` file.

In other words, the primary differences between `git diff --full-index <parent> <child> | git apply -3` and `git cherry-pick <child>` is that the former will not detect renames during the fall-back "three-way patch" operation, and will even not try a three-way merge on any one file if it's able to do the patch application without that.  It is, I think, difficult (but not impossible) to construct artificial examples in which these produce very different outcomes, but I don't have time to do that right now.

---

<sup>1</sup>Things get a little complex here since "the current version" is not necessarily the HEAD version.  Specifically, `git apply` uses the work-tree version as the `--ours` variant, while `git apply --index` uses the index version as the `--ours` variant.  The `git cherry-pick` command, however, requires that the index and work-tree be "clean" by default, i.e., match the `HEAD` commit.  In this case, there's normally no difference between "the HEAD version", "the index version", and "the work-tree version".

Comment: First of all, this is one great answer. It will take me some more time to fully underdstand every peace of it so hold on ;-)... Those kind of answers give me a good homework. Now I finished to learn blobs & trees and also I'm learning diff from the start and __I can't understand why you are talking about `full-index`. From the docs - it's only printing to full blob names. Why is this so important for you to mention it & what is the connection beteween `--full-index <commit1> <commit2> | git apply -3` to _three-way merges_?__.

Comment: First, some background: `git diff --full-index ... | git apply -3` is, in essence, what the non-interactive `git rebase` does (except it uses `git format-patch` and `git am` instead of `git diff` and repeated `git apply`). The full index is only needed if the shortened index is ambiguous. There was a fix in Git version 1.7.10 to make `git diff` produce unambiguous-for-the-current-repository hashes, but they may become ambiguous if more objects are stored in the repository. Moreover, if you're stuck with Git 1.7 or 1.7.1 (eg CentOS), `git diff | ...` may not provide a long enough index hash.

Comment: Now: It's really the `-3` in `git apply -3` that turns `git apply` into a three-way merge. You don't need `--full-index` in most cases, since a modern Git will produce a sufficiently-long abbreviation in the `index` line. But it's a good habit to use `--full-index` here if you're coding some script. [The `git-rebase--am.sh` script does this, for instance.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7668cbc60578f99a4c048f8f8f38787930b8147b/git-rebase--am.sh#L54)