# How to create interdiff between two file with git?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

We have two patch files, patch-old.patch and patch-new.patch and we want to generate an interdiff file. How can we do this?

We have tried the following using [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/about), but it results in an empty `interdiff.txt` file.

```
git diff path/to/patch-old.patch path/to/patch-new.patch > interdiff.text
```

When we do the following, it doesn't show anything in Git Bash

```
git diff path/to/patch-old.patch path/to/patch-new.patch
```

Comment: Git doesn't really "do" interdiffs (although there are tricks to do it; see https://www.drupal.org/documentation/git/interdiff). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/17792768/1256452. On Linux, use the `interdiff` command (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/interdiff.1.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides my earlier comment (which is aimed at getting you the result you want, rather than just answering your question), if your two files `path/to/patch-new|old.patch` are both inside a Git repository and you are inside a Git repository, you must use `git diff --no-index` to diff them.  This is true even if the files are not tracked.

For instance, in my Git repository for Git:

```
$ git diff git-svn git-tag
$ git diff --no-index git-svn git-tag
diff --git a/git-svn b/git-tag
index 6145bf5e2..bbee2ad7a 100755
Binary files a/git-svn and b/git-tag differ
```