# Diff between commit deltas, not commits themselves

Tags: git, diff, delta

I have two branches coming from commit `a`:

`a - b - c
   \ d - e`

What I want to see is a diff between the *changes* introduced in `c` and `e`. I can easily view the differences between `e` and `c` themselves, but that's not what I want, because that diff includes changes introduced in `b` and `d`, and those two commits are different from each other. Abstractly I guess what I want would be something like

`diff(diff(b, c), diff(d, e))`

Is there a good way to do this? The edits introduced in `c` and `e` are only different by maybe 50 lines, so it's not that many, the problem is that this 50 line signal is getting lost in the ~1000 line noise from the difference between `b` and `d`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are c and e very similar but different a bit? Or c and e are completely not related?

Comment: There is a program that diffs diffs, called "interdiff". It is not part of Git, but you can install it and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, the interdiff lead was enough to help me find the answered question [How do I get the interdiff between these two git commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792768/how-do-i-get-the-interdiff-between-these-two-git-commits).

The simple answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793943/5156887) was to use
`diff <(git log -p -1 c) <(git log -p -1 e)`

and the better answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278675/5156887 ) if you have git 2.19 is the builtin `git range-diff`. I didn't have that new of a version so I couldn't find it.

Comment: This is the best self-answer I've seen in a long time. Well researched and informative. Also, excellent job balancing out the links to other answers against summarizing the content of the links.

Comment: I had forgotten about the new range-diff feature. Note that it's substantially more complex than a simple interdiff, though.

Comment: Why does the "simple" version don't use `git show`, i.e. something like `diff <(git show c) <(git show e)`? Seems to be even more simple.