How to compare the DIFF of two merges/merge requests with different bases
Is there a good way to compare the diff (so basically the diff of the diff) between two merges or even better two potential merges (aka merge requests).
For some context the branching pattern: There is a master M for each stable release (M1, M2, ...)
A continuous development branch D which gets merged into the master for each release.
Now if i want to fix a bug i do it in a fix branch F to merge that into develop.
I also want to supply fixes for the same issues to someone using an older stable release M1. For that reason there is an open bugfix branch B1 based on the old M1 commit. I reimplement the fix on branch F* to merge it into B1. Ideally the implemented fix is the same, but there might be some small adjustments since they are implemented on different bases.
Now back to the question: I want to compare the two open merges F*->B1 and F->D to see what exactly those small adjustments are. Is there a good way to do this?
     --F*
    /   
   B1---B1
  /    
 M1---M2---M3
  \   /    /
   --D----D----D
           \  
            F

I tried various git commands and options in git extensions and BC3, but didnt get any useful results.

Generate patches from each diff. Then diff that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278675/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+interdiff
