# Saving the entire git diff between two commits in a text file

Tags: git, diff

is there a way where I could save the entire difference between two diff in a text file?

Suppose I wanted all the changes between `A1` and `A10` on `master` branch.

```
--A11-A10-A9-A8-A7-A6-A5-A4-A3-A2-A1-master
```

Or, is there a way where I could get the entire diff in Terminal which I could copy+paste?

Comment: `git diff master~10 master >changes.diff` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git diff commits difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191282/git-diff-commits-difference)

Comment: Any way I can get just the file names?

Answer (score 71):

Sure:

```
git diff A10..A1 > my.diff
```

Comment: Note that in `git diff` the `A..B` notation is **convenience** feature: diff operates on ***endpoints*** not on *range*, so for diff `A..B` really means `A B`.

Answer (score 18):

```
git diff {commit1} {commit2} > diff.txt
```

Being {commit1} and {commit2} a reference to the initial and finish commits you want to compare (reference could be an entire or partial SHA, a tag, HEAD.....)

Answer (score 8):

If you just need save diff between **two recent commits**, you can use this command as well:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD > diff.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

From man page..

```
git format-patch -k --stdout R1..R2
```

Answer (score 4):

to get all folder/filenames as output from diff use

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2> --name-only
```