# How to create a git branch with custom diff to master branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

Sorry for the vague question title, I don't know how to phrase it better. Basically I have a `master` branch with two commits `c1` and `c2`:

```
    +-----> dummy1   +-----> dummy2
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
    |                |
  c1+              c2+
   .                 .
   └── a.txt +       ├── a.txt
                     ├── b.txt +
                     ├── not-wanted.txt +
                     └── c.txt +
```

`c1` has added `a.txt` file. `c2` has added three more files as you see. Now I wanna have two dummy branches, one off of `c1` and another from `c2` so that when I do `git diff dummy1..dummy2` I only see the file `b.txt` and `c.txt` in the diff. So the resulting PR between `dummy1<-dummy2` only shows `b.txt` and `c.txt` but not the `not-wanted.txt`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: you'll need some *new* commits.  You can't get what you want with your existing commits.

#### Long

Git isn't about branches or files: Git is all about *commits*.  Pull requests<sup>2</sup> use branch names, but only so that Git can find *commits*.

In other words, everything is always about commits.  Names—branch names like `master` or `develop`, or tag names like `v2.1`, or remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, or even pull requests on GitHub—really just identify *one specific commit*.  Each commit *holds* files—a complete snapshot of *all* files, in fact—along with metadata like who made it (user name and email address), when (date-and-time-stamp), and why (log message).

The fact that there's more than one commit *in* a branch, or in a pull request, occurs because each commit records its *parent* commit, by hash ID.  Every commit has its own unique hash ID, and every commit<sup>1</sup> says *... and if you want to know what comes before me, look to commit XXXXXX*, where the `X`s are the previous commit's hash ID.

So, in your setup, you have a series of commits on your master that either ends at `c2` or goes on further:

```
...--B--c1--c2--D--E--F--G   <--master
```

Someone else might have a series of commits, in their repository, that ends at `B`.  If so, you can make a name that points to `c1`, giving you:

```
...--B--c1   <-- name1
          \
           c2--D--...--G   <-- master
```

If you now make a pull request to someone else using `name1`, you're asking that someone else—whose chain of commits ends at `B`—to copy your commit `c1` into their repository, and set some name of *theirs* to point to `c1`.

You can also make a name pointing to `c2`:

```
...--B--c1   <-- name1
          \
           c2   <-- name2
             \
              D--...--G   <-- master
```

and make a pull request using your `name2`, which asks that someone to incorporate *both `c1` and `c2`* into their repository and set one of their names to point to `c2`.

No matter what you do, you're always going to be asking them—whoever they are—to take their branch-name that points to existing shared commit `B`, which is already in their repository as well as in yours, and add new commits on to the end of their commit `B`.  What you control is which *specific commit* you ask them to use.  They will take every commit from their end—their copy of `B`—to this new tip commit.  So you can make a new commit, let's call it `c3`, that comes after `c1`, that you remember via branch name `name3`:

```
           c3   <-- name3
          /
...--B--c1--c2--D--E--F--G   <--master
```

This commit `c3` has whatever contents you like.  You then send them a pull request asking them to set *their* `master` (or whatever other branch name) so that instead of pointing to shared commit `B`, they copy commits `c1` and `c3` into their repository and then set their name to point to `c3`.

To do that:

```
$ git checkout -b name3 <hash-of-c1>
... make whatever changes you like, e.g., git cherry-pick -n <hash-of-c2>
... fix things up, git add files as needed ...
$ git commit
```

to create new commit `c3` to which your branch name `name3` will point.  Then you can make a pull request using this `name3` name and new `c3` commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>At least one commit in every non-empty repository has *no* parent: that's the very first commit, which has no previous commit because it can't.  Some commits have two, or possibly even more, parents: these are *merge* commits.  Most commits just have one parent, though.  Git's history *is* the commits, strung together using the backwards-looking chain formed by working backwards from the *last* commit, found by some branch name, one commit at a time (or two or more when reaching a merge).

<sup>2</sup>Pull requests are not actually part of Git itself: they're add-ons, provided by places like GitHub and Bitbucket.  What Git provides are the commits themselves and methods—`git fetch` and `git push`—for receiving and sending commits between peer repositories.  Before GitHub, people would clone a Linux repo, make new commits, and then email patches around for review and revision ... and in fact, they still do that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want not-wanted.txt to show up, it looks like you need to create a new commit after deleting not-wanted.txt.

```
Delete not-wanted.txt
git commit -m "c3"
```

Now create the two branches from c1 and c3

```
git branch dummy-1 c1
git branch dummy-2 c3
```

If you also want not-wanted.txt file to be backed up in some branch, you can create branch at c2:

```
git branch backup-branch c2
```

Comment: How do I exclude the `not-wanted.txt`?

Comment: Edited the answer as per the requirement

Comment: Note that if you just add `c3` after `c2` (so that `c3` has `c2` as parent), you'll send them all the commits up to and including `c3`. When they extract `c3` they won't see the unwanted file, but it will be in their now-shared `c2` commit copy.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create separate branches. You can diff between commits in your current branch:

```
git diff c1 c2
```

Then, if needed, use the diff to create a patch: [How to see the changes between two commits without commits in-between?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191282/how-to-see-the-changes-between-two-commits-without-commits-in-between)

Comment: Thanks but I need branches to have a pull request. So the PR only focus on few files rather than all the changes.